# Text is not displayed when I remove and reapply the layout in Snackbar

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, snackbar

When I am trying to remove the snackbar's parent layout and recreate the snackbar with the same layout, the value of textView comes out blank.

I have also tried debugging the same, while using the debugger I am getting the text string but it is not displayed in the snackbar at runtime.

Here is the XML file of my custom SnackBar :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/dr_toast_round_corners_10dp_red"
    android:id="@+id/toast_container">
    
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_error"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_error_red"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_invalid_credentials"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/dimen_16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/inter_regular"
        tools:text="@string/invalid_credentials_login"
        android:textColor="@color/text_body_light"
        android:textSize="@dimen/dimen_13sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/iv_close"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_error"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_24dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dimen_12dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the SnackBar's code :

```
fun showCustomErrorSnackbar(view: ViewGroup, activity: Activity, message: String) {
    snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
    snackbar.duration = 2000

    val customLayout =
        activity.layoutInflater.inflate(
            R.layout.layout_custom_toast,
            activity.findViewById(R.id.toast_container)
        )
    snackbar.view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
    val textview = customLayout.findViewById<AppCompatTextView>(R.id.tv_invalid_credentials)
    textview.text = message

    // now change the layout of the snackbar
    val snackbarLayout = snackbar.view as Snackbar.SnackbarLayout
    snackbarLayout.removeAllViewsInLayout()
    // set padding of the all corners as 0
    customLayout.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0)
    val layoutParameters = FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
    layoutParameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
    layoutParameters.setMargins(24, 16, 24, 0) //left = 24, top = 16, right = 24, bottom = 0
    snackbarLayout.layoutParams = layoutParameters
    val closeSnackbar = customLayout.findViewById<AppCompatImageView>(R.id.iv_close)
    closeSnackbar.setOnClickListener {
        snackbar.dismiss()
    }
    val parent = customLayout.parent as? ViewGroup
    parent?.removeView(customLayout)

    snackbarLayout.addView(customLayout, 0)
    snackbar.show()
}
```

For the first time the snackbar is shown like this :

[image: Snackbar for the first time]

But soon after it is displayed like this :

[image: Second Time Snackbar(Actual issue)]

Can anyone help me in solving this?

I want the snackbar to perform perfectly without skipping the texts or the layout. And Also I want to close the snackbar at the cross button click listener.